# Bottom Slide Panel - jQuery & CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideup

I wanted to create a slide up panel like [Simple Sidebar](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar/), but it needs to slide up from the bottom and should be adjustable to 2 heights and self adjusting content on the top which should make the division scrollable.

I have designed the code based on the [Simple Sidebar](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar/), but for me it doesn't work the way it is needed, it overlays over the text instead of compressing the height.

Stage 1 (when **h** is clicked)
[image]

Stage 2 (when **h1** is clicked)
[image]

HTML

```
   <div id="down-wrapper">
      <div id="top-content-wrapper">
       ....
       <button href="#" id="down-toggle">H</button>
       <button href="#" id="down-toggle1">H1</button>
      </div>
      <div id="downbar-wrapper">Click</div>
   </div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#down-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#down-wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    $("#down-toggle1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#down-wrapper").toggleClass("toggled1");
    });


})
```

I couldn't write my CSS, all stuff could be found in the plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/uX5qqQgVBZKEgARBeG23?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 absolute elements in your **#down-wrapper**. But you forgot to adjust the height of your **#top-content-wrapper** when either one of the buttons is clicked.

Also overflowing text on a page would add a scrollbar. So you will need to add an overflow scroll property on your **#top-content-wrapper** which will take over your page scrollbar whenever the **#downbar-wrapper** is shown.

Change these in your **Plunker CSS** file:

```
#down-wrapper.toggled #top-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}

#down-wrapper.toggled1 #top-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Into:

```
#down-wrapper.toggled #top-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
    height:55%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#down-wrapper.toggled1 #top-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
    height:10%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
```

}

Comment: Can you answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229591/bottom-sliding-panel-absolute-position